# Android Studio Emulator not loading Windows 10

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation, windows-10

I have a fresh install of android studio on Windows 10, with all the packages for android api 22. When I run the emulator I get the following message

```
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd foo -netspeed full -netdelay none
emulator: device fd:928
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
```

I can see the emulator in the task manager, but it doesn't actually load.

I've been looking for answers to why it doesn't load and I've made sure all the ram settings are correct, but I don't understand why the emulator won't load.

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

HAXM, the Intel Android Virtualization Technology is incompatible with Hyper-V.  Turn off Hyper-V and give it a go again.  Hyper-V will often be installed if you have installed Visual Studio with Windows Phone tools.

Or from an admin command prompt run the following.
Note to get an admin cmd prompt, right-mouse the windows icon, click Command Prompt (Admin ).

To turn off Hyper-V run this: 
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
and then reboot

To turn Hyper-V back on, run this: 
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
And then reboot

You can turn off Hyper-V in the services menu (type "Services" in the Search thingy), and also use the Services menu to turn it back on. Even though it may not be necessary I still reboot after doing it this way.

Blog post on this here - http://www.devfish.net/post/2015/08/18/error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration-android-on-windows.aspx

Healy in Tampa

Comment: So we cannot develop Windows Phone & Android Apps together?

Comment: @teoman - you can if you use the visual studio emulator for android which runs in hyperv.  you can also do it by turning hyperv on / off.

Comment: @JoeHealy Thank you a ton, I was stuck since last week after updating Windows 10 Insider Beta Channel Preview.

Though even after running `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` , the task manager shows CPU Virtualization: Enabled. I thought this command will set that to Disabled.

But anyways, it started the emulator running back again.

Answer (score -1):

This has a very simple solution only if the installation process is complete and still the emulator is not launching, Solution: Just try to use older API version or any older stable android API version. In my case, the latest version I was having was API-31, but the API-28 worked for me. Change you android API to any older version Try it. This worked for me.