# Android Studio emulator keeps waiting on Android boot screen in Windows 10 x64

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, windows-10

I am new to Android development. Here is my system:

Windows 10 Enterprise 64 bit

Intel Core i7 4790 CPU @ 3.60 GHZ

8 GB ram

I have installed Android Studio 1.5.1

[image]

When I try to run Hello World app, The emulator works, but keeps waiting on Android boot screen. I waited a lot, it doesnt make sense. Just keeps waiting. When I try to run from CMD, the result is the same. Here is the output in CMD.

```
 C:\WINDOWS\system32>C:\Users\UserDesktop\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5_API_23_x86 -netspeed full -netdelay none
C:\WINDOWS\system32>emulator: device fd:808

HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
creating window 61 83 462 820
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered

emulator: UpdateChecker: skipped version check
```

And these are some screenshots from Android studio.

[image][image][image][image]

I have tried to turn off Hyper-V : 
    bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off 
and then reboot   ... from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31828561/android-studio-emulator-not-loading-windows-10)

What shall I do more to be able run emulator correctly? I have also Visual Studio 2015 installed. and it works perfectly in Universal Windows apps. Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **[Genymotion emulator](https://www.genymotion.com/)** for Android Development which is much faster and reliable and of course really easy to set up and configure.

Comment: Thanks but I need to solve my problem first. Maybe Genymotion will not work as well. I need to solve this basic problem.

Comment: It will definitely work and there's no problem with other installations of you. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

i suggest you connect your android phone as emulator

For Devices Running with Android V3.2 or Older:

For these Devices you can access the Developer options by going to  Settings –> Applications –> Development. There you should enable USB Debugging.
b. For Devices Running with newer Versions From Android  V4.0:

For these Devices, The Developer options are not visible by default. You can access the Developer options by going to Settings –> About Phone –> Build Number. Now tap the Build Number for 7 Times so you can gain Access to Developer options. Now you can see a Toast Displaying that you are now a developer. Now return back to Settings. There you can now see Developer options above About Tablet. Enter into Developer Options and There you must enable USB Debugging.

Now the Final step is to Install Drivers for your Windows to detect the device. For mac, it is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But first of all, I would like to run on pc. You are right but that is my next step.